# C, Call to function twice, one writes to file, one writes to terminal

Tags: c

fairly new to C and have a slight issue,

I have a function which is filled with 'fprintf' statements and some calculations relevant to the output.
When I call it from main() it works correctly and prints to the document, I then want to call it a second time and have the same text but only outputted to the terminal (as in printf).

I have a flag in the function parameters which would specify this choice but no way of accomplishing it aside from an if statement for every fprintf saying:

```
if (flag == 1)
{ 
    fprintf(pt, "Random text...
} else { 
    printf("The same random text...
}
```

Which seems dreadfully inefficient. My other idea was to (with my little understanding of it) use #define within the function in the context:

```
if (flag== 1)
{
    #define fprintf(pt, printf(
}
```

Which not only seemed very cheap but did not work.

Any ideas would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: What about making a UNIX-style program and just printing the output to `stdout` and let the user redirect it where it wants? `tee` might be helpful here. If you'll be printing to the same document for all program executions, though, this doesn't make as much sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
FILE *out=stdout;

fprintf(out,"Hello World\n");
```

Since this is a function, you can pass in the `out` pointer as an argument. When printing to the terminal, just assign `stdout` to it.

Comment: I use this for writing `void about(FILE* outFp)` functions that can either write the "about this application" message to `stdout` or `stderr` depending on whether I am passing in a `--help` option, or if the program ends in an error state.

Comment: Oh that's great! Thanks for the help

Comment: @BodneyC no problem at all! Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

you could do a ternary expression using the fact that `printf(` is equivalent to `fprintf(stdout,`:

```
fprintf(flag == 1 ? pt : stdout, "Random text...");
```

Comment: definitely.  Since your using it in a function, don't use a flag but rather pass it in as a parameter and don't forget to `fflush(out)`

Comment: the `flag` thing is a bit off, yes, because if set to 1, it needs `pt` to be a valid handle. It would be useful to dynamically select if goes to stdout or to the handle. But the other solution by abacles makes more sense, he hadn't the pressure of being the first one answering so he had time to think :). BTW is flushing `stdout` necessary when you put a newline in the end? in what does it differ from `printf` in that area?

Comment: Wonderful, works a charm
I was unaware that that was how printf worked
Thanks again